# Ghusl for Friday prayers

Tags: wudu, ghusl, jumuah

If I do ghusl and I am not in the state of janaba, but I wash every part and rinse my nose and mouth just like in the ghusl I do for janaba, do I need to make wudu after getting out of the shower again?

And if yes can I make the wudu right after the ghusl, inside of the shower?

Thanks,

Comment: You can do wudu inside the shower. As to whether the minimal ghusl of Friday itself suffices for wudu, there is disagreement on it. See https://islamqa.info/en/answers/146304/

Answer (score 0):

If you do ghusl for the state of janaba, then you don't have to make Wudu, but if you do ghusl only as Sunnah (without janaba) then you have to make wudu.